# Is Solr 4 Production Ready?

Tags: solr, lucene, search-engine

We are right now integrating Solr Search with one of the shopping cart application. I have read several suggestions here on stackoverflow to use Solr 4 for having a support for join in indexes.

My Question is, Is Solr 4 production ready? And more importantly using a join between two indexes have any performance impact?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the [Road Map](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solr4.0) for Solr 4.0

The current roadmap discussed by the devs (as of May 2012) for 4.0 is:

- 4.0-alpha release sometime in Jun/Jul 2012.
- 4.0-beta release no sooner then 30 days after 4.0-alpha. The beta release may contain additional features & API changes compared to the alpha release, but should not change the index format unless absolutely necessary to fix a bug.
- 4.0 (final) release no sooner then 30 days after 4.0-beta. The final release may contain additional features and API additions compared to the beta release, but should not change any APIs (or the index format) from the beta release unless absolutely necessary to fix a bug.

Also, I don't think Solr supports join across Indexes. The entities need to be within the index. But you can confirm.
For performance, I think it would be better to ask on the Solr forums.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Elastic Search](http://www.elasticsearch.org/).
It is is production ready, built on top of Lucene, ready for horizontal scaling & sharding and also supports searching across multiple indexes.

Comment: Yes, this is a good suggestion, I'll try when I have some more time. For our current needs we have implemented Solr 3.6

Comment: Sure, if you like, please vote up.
Also I should add that according to the source from [here](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-dev/201210.mbox/%3CCAOdYfZW27OoUqXeZo6TmWZUSQhf=e8fUCx6xaUmYHFmszUAamg@mail.gmail.com%3E) Apache has announced Solr 4.0 final.